# How to print Vec<u8> in lldb?

Tags: rust, lldb

I want to print a vec using ascii format byte by byte.

```
let slice1 = b"abcdefg";
```

I can print the struct like this:

```
(lldb) p slice1
(&[u8]) slice1 = {
  data_ptr = 0x00007ff9abe00020
  length = 7
}
```

When I try to print the whole data:

```
(lldb) p/c *slice1.data_ptr
(u8) *data_ptr = 'a'
```

Is there a way to print out all its seven bytes?

Comment: You could use `rust-lldb`, or get a rather ugly output with `parray 7 slice1.data_ptr`

Comment: @Aplet123 Add that as an answer then?

Comment: x/10cb *slice1.data_ptr

Comment: Write a pretty-printer for lldb. See: https://github.com/servo/string-cache/issues/240#issuecomment-913907876