# Debugging Rust on Vscode : u8 not shown correctly

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust

I am debugging this simple Rust program on Vscode

```rust
fn main() {
    let u8: u8 = 3;
    let b: u16 = 5;
    let c: u32 = 7;
    let d: u64 = 9;
}
```

The values of these variables are displayed correctly, except for `u8`

[image]

I'm curious, is there a reason or a solution for this issue? Thank you!

**Edit**
Here's my `launch.json` configuration. I also followed a tutorial and installed the C/C++ extension with `"type": "cppvsdbg"`, but it gives me the same result.

I'm also adding that I am a Rust newbie :)

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<your program>",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Edit**
Thanks to @Unapiedra & @ChayimFriedman, for their answers and insights. I couldn't solve this problem. But here's what I tried, someone might pick it up in the future

1. I autogenerated `launch.json` (thx @Unapiedra)
2. Following this [doc](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/blob/master/MANUAL.md#stdio), I added this to my launch configuration

```
    "preRunCommands": [
        "type format add --format hex int" // This is a test from lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html
      ]
```

But it didn't work. I also tried `initCommands` to no avail.

Comment: What are you using for debugging?

Comment: @PitaJ, I added info about my debug configuration

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Related (but not solved): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980553/how-to-print-vecu8-in-lldb

Comment: The reason is that *lldb* is choosing to show your 'u8' as a hex. There is a way to have lldb format it using `decimal` using the format character `d`. However, I don't know how to get this VsCode debugger frontend to show it that way. https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because you are using the C++ extension not the Rust extension for the debugger.

LLDB or the debugger frontend in VSCode needs to guess the type of your `a` variable. And it interprets the byte to show it in hex formatting.

On my setup, it works out of the box. I posted my `launch.json` below. This was autogenerated by VsCode. I would guess that the *RustAnalyzer* extension is the driver of this.

The autogeneration was triggered by me clicking on the Debugging tab, then clicking on 'create a launch.json file'. And then I get a prompt that Cargo.toml has been detected and I can generate debug targets.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'q72117996'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=q72117996",
                    "--package=q72117996"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "q72117996",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'q72117996'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--bin=q72117996",
                    "--package=q72117996"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "q72117996",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is because `u8` is `typedef`ed to be C's `char` and it shows C `char` as... well, a character.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried your solution with no succes. I edited my post to describe what I did. But I'm abandoning this problem for now :)

Comment: I deleted the `launch.json` config, and did a new autogeneration with the detected `Cargo.toml` as per this answer. `u8` variables are still wrongly shown as `char` in the "Run And Debug" side panel. Not a solution for the question.